# Conditional use of functions?

Tags: bash

I created a bash script that parses ASCII files into a comma delimited output. It's worked great. Now, a new file layout for these files is being gradually introduced.

My script has now two parsing functions (one per layout) that I want to call depending on a specific marker that is present in the ASCII file header. The script is structured thusly:

```
#!/bin/bash

function parseNewfile() {...parse stuff...return stuff...}
function parseOldfile() {...parse stuff...return stuff...}

#loop thru ASCII files array
i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
    #check if file contains marker for new layout
        grep CSVHeaderBox output_$i.ASC
        #calls parsing function based on exit code
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
        CXD=`parseNewfile`
        else
        CXD=`parseOldfile`
        fi

    echo ${array[$i]}| awk -v cxd=`echo $CXD` ....
        let i++
done>>${outdir}/outfile.csv
...
```

The script does not err out. It always calls the original function "parseOldfile" and ignores the new one. Even when I specifically feed my script with several files with the new layout.

What I am trying to do seem very trivial. What am I missing here?

EDIT: Samples of old and new file layouts.

1) OLD File Layout

```
F779250B
=====BOX INFORMATION=====
Model         = R15-100
Man Date      = 07/17/2002
BIST Version  = 3.77
SW Version    = 0x122D
SW Name       = v1b1645
HW Version    = 1.1
Receiver ID   = 00089787556

=====DISK INFORMATION=====
....
```

2) NEW File Layout

```
F779250B
=====BOX INFORMATION=====
Model         = HR22-100
Man Date      = 07/17/2008
BIST Version  = 7.55
SW Version    = 0x066D
SW Name       = v18m1fgu
HW Version    = 2.3
Receiver ID   = 028910170936

CSVHeaderBox:Platform,ManufactureDate,BISTVersion,SWVersion,SWName,HWRevision,RID
CSVValuesBox:HR22-100,20080717,7.55,0x66D,v18m1fgu,2.3,028910170936

=====DISK INFORMATION=====
....
```

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. The grep + if works for a simple example.

Comment: `grep` doesn't seem to find the string `CSVHeaderBox` in the file `output_$i.ASC`. Show sample content of such a file.

Comment: Do you see `CSVHeaderBox` in the output?

Comment: You'll want to add `-q` and `-s` to grep's options.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I'll provide one in my original post. Stand by.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your problem, but a potential performance boost: instead of

```
    grep CSVHeaderBox output_$i.ASC
    #calls parsing function based on exit code
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

use

```
    if grep -q CSVHeaderBox output_$i.ASC
```

qrep -q will exit successfully on the first match, so it doesn't have to scan the whole file. Plus you don't have to bother with the $? var.

Don't do this:

```
awk -v cxd=`echo $CXD`
```

Do this:

```
awk -v cxd="$CXD"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves the OP's requirement.
What's the need for `awk` if your function knows how to parse the file?

```
#/bin/bash

function f1() {
    echo "f1() says $@"
}

function f2() {
    echo "f2() says $@"
}

FUN="f1"
${FUN} "foo"
FUN="f2"
${FUN} "bar"
```

Comment: Awk is here to clean up the output of the function before writing it to my CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit embarrassed to write this but I solved my "problem".

After gedit (I am on Ubuntu) err-ed out several dozen times about "Trailing spaces", I copied and pasted my code into a new file and re-run my script.

It worked.

I have no explanation why.

Thanks to everyone for taking the time.